# "The obvious question here is how does ..." - Does this sentence require a question mark?

Tags: questions, punctuation

According to the Chicago Manual of Style Guide (17th Ed.)

> **"An indirect question never takes a question mark."** (6.69: Direct and indirect questions)
>
> - "How the two could be reconciled was the question on everyone’s mind." (CMoS)

---

I wrote the following sentence:

> The obvious question here is **how exactly does the program determine "employment opportunities"**.

I can't quite figure out if it should take a question mark or not. I think it is an indirect question (a statement with an embedded question in bold) and should not take a question mark.

However, when I looked up *"the obvious question here"* in google news, I found both versions - with and without the question mark (but mostly with the question mark).

> **Question mark not used:**
>
> 1. The obvious question here is how to define “everyone.” - [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/georgebradt/2019/06/08/how-the-uber-change-agent-survives-his-own-change/#4f5c17916539)
> 2. The important question is whether the crisis will last longer than the ECB assumes. - [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/on-small-business/what-the-ecb-actually-meant-to-say-on-thursday/2020/03/13/10b65ca4-6541-11ea-8a8e-5c5336b32760_story.html)
>
> **Question mark used:**
>
> 3. The obvious question here is how do women, who still earn less than men on average, manage to own more property than single men? - [NBC News](https://www.nbcnews.com/better/lifestyle/single-women-own-more-homes-single-men-here-s-what-ncna1134926)
> 4. The important question is whether a lock box sitting on a porch is a real deterrent?  - [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/marcwebertobias/2020/03/13/two-security-products-that-deter-package-theft-by-porch-pirates-are-they-really-worth-it/#4c4b11312735) (haha this is wrong!)

I want to know if my sentence is an indirect question (I think it is) and if I should not put a question mark at the end.

Comment: No, it's a main clause interrogative.  Subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions) do not have subject-auxiliary inversion. The embedded equivalent would be "The obvious question here is how exactly the program determines "employment opportunities".

Comment: @BillJ I don't understand those terms at all. Are you saying that my original sentence is not an indirect question, and that it needs a question mark?

Comment: Yes, but only where the interrogative (question) is complement of the verb "be", as it is in your example. Incidentally, I would add a colon after "is", as in "The obvious question here is: How exactly does the program determine "employment opportunities?".

Comment: I am trying to learn (through google) what you mean by those terms to better understand your comment. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with BillJ. By the way, in your four examples, Number 4 is wrong. Imagine yourself speaking to someone. 1) Can you ask them, "How to define 'everyone'?" No: it's not a question. 2) Can you ask them, "Whether the crisis will last longer?" Likewise, no. 3) Can you ask them, "How do women...?" YES. That IS a question. 4) Can you ask them, "Whether a lock box is a deterrent?" NO. This one's wrong. It's not a question.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian You are right. That makes sense. However, I still don't feel this is idiomatic *"The obvious question here is how exactly the program determines employment opportunities"* It doesn't sound natural for some reason - but it is grammatical and follows the rules that BillJ pointed out. Do you think it's because I mention "question" in the sentence? May be the use of "question" warrants the use of "how **does**" and a question mark. What do you think?